# Pylint type confusion

Tags: python, pylint

```py
user = get_user() # returns object of type User or False
if not user:
  raise HTTPException()
print(user.name) # pylint error: Instance of 'bool' has no 'name' member
```

Goal: get rid of pylint error in the last line.

I tried to use a Union[bool, User] return type for `get_user()` but this didn't solve the issue.

What's the pythonic way of 'casting' the type from bool to User?

Comment: Please note that answers shouldn't be in questions - you can post an answer below or just delete the question. But yes I would say `None` is the pythonic return value for a missing user; the downside of `Union[bool, User]` is that `if not user` only rules out `False`, not `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the return type of the `get_user()` function to `typing.Optional[User]` solves the problem.

pylint is complaining because, according to the type hint *only*, `user` might be the value `True`, and `True.name` would raise an exception. pylint does not evaluate the *code path* (it doesn't know if `get_user()` returns only `False`, not `True`; it just knows that it is supposed to return a bool.)

Comment: Going to delete my comment since it doesn't belong in the comments, and you should accept your own answer :) For other people that might find the question useful, a little bit of additional explanation in your answer about the _why_ (as mentioned in the comments) would be useful.